# Que tecnologia/ferramenta utilizar para detectar/filtrar notificações que chegam no pc (Windows) pelo Chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Boa noite,
eu gostaria de fazer um pequeno projeto da seguinte forma:
Têm-se notificações que chegam ao windows pelo google chrome, isto é, pelos sites que as notificações estão habilitadas, como o WhatsApp Web, youtube, etc., que me avisam quando mensagens novas chegam ou quando videos de canais que eu sigo são postados. Eu gostaria de fazer um programa que 'detectasse' quando essas notificações chegassem para mim e dessa forma eu gostaria de acender um LED que está conectado à porta USB do meu computador. Dessa forma, quando eu tivesse notificações e não estivesse olhando para a tela do computador, ao chegar perto veria o LED aceso e saberia que notificações novas chegaram.
Que tecnologia ou ferramenta eu poderia utilizar para a execução desse projeto?